# Expo app crashes on start when loaded from EAS Update, after upgrading to SDK 49

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

I am running a **managed** app which I just upgraded to SDK 49.
eas-cli/3.17.1 darwin-arm64 node-v18.17.0

My app, even tough running great locally, crashes on start when I open it from an EAS update usin the Expo Go app.
I have tried investigating it for 3 days now and couldn't fix it.

I used XCode 'console' app to get the error logged when the Expo Go app is crashing.
Here are the 3 error logs I found there:

> - Expo Go RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (native stack depth), js engine: hermes
> - Expo Go Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
>
>   - Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
>   - A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes
> - Expo Go NSInvalidArgumentException: -[EXReactAppExceptionHandler handleFatalJSExceptionWithMessage:stack:exceptionId:extraDataAsJSON:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281fa8380

After Googling these I realized that the one I should focus on is the first one (the 'RangeError') since the others are just a result of it, and that the issue is probably caused by one of my dependencies failing for some reason.

Looking into that made me suspect 'react-native-reanimated' (because of [that Github issue](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/4151)), so I tried downgrading back to 2.14.4 which is the previous version I used, and when I ran that locally the app crashed with the error:

> TypeError: _ReanimatedModule.default.createNode is not a function (it is undefined), js engine: hermes

Followed by the same: "main" has not been registered error, so I thought it was worth mentioning.

Then I used `npx expo prebuild -p ios` and ran that using XCode, which worked fine at first,
but after a few runs suddenly crashed with this:

> ReanimatedError: Maximum call stack size exceeded (native stack depth). , js engine: reanimated

I also tried switching the jsEngine to JSC but all it did was giving me even less usefull error logs.

I already thought I figured it out twice now but then a day later I make a new EAS update and it crashes again, so I couldn't even get consistency there.

Here are package.json dependencies changes made during my upgrade to SDK 49. No other changes to any of my code base were made between a working version and a crashing version, only these dependencies changes.

[image: package.json dependencies changes made during my upgrade to SDK 49]

I am really frustrated.. would appreciate your help so much

Comment: No unfortunately I didn't.. I even contacted Expo's support but they weren't able to reproduce the issue on their end. After 2 weeks of effort I gave up and downgraded back to SDK 48. Hopefully when SDK 50 comes along it won't happen there

Comment: I ended up doing the exact same thing as well. I guess we have to make do with 48 for now

Comment: Have you tried using node 16 instead of 18? I was using v16 and everything worked normally. After installing v18, update would only create the android bundle. Could only get to work again by returning to v16.

Comment: I had similar issues when upgrading from expo sdk 47 to expo 49, to fix the "main has not been registered." issue I followed expo recommendation here https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/migrating/#custom-main-entry-point-in-packagejson-is-not-supported I had to rename my App.js to index.js as well. Then the main dependency causing issues for me was react-native-reanimated: 3.3.0 I can't upgrade to latest since this is the one required by expo go but if I remove this library then it works. Im looking into alternatives or I will endup replacing react-native-reanimated for something else.

Comment: I have the same issue, the only error or warning I get is: "ERROR  ViewPropTypes will be removed from React Native, along with all other PropTypes. We recommend that you migrate away from PropTypes and switch to a type system like TypeScript. If you need to continue using ViewPropTypes, migrate to the 'deprecated-react-native-prop-types' package."  I've patching the react-native package as some suggest on SO but nothing works, not even sure if this is causing the crash as works fine locally